Move task to other sprint in Azure Boards
Is there a way to move the closed and active task to next sprint which is part of a story without manually moving each of the closed task

there is no automatic way to move the closed and active task to next sprint currently, please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

There is no automatic way to move the closed and active task to next sprint which is part of a story.

You can manually reassign the closed or active tasks to next sprint in Sprint backlog.
Please refer to the doc End-of-sprint activities for the details.
